# I cannot remove two shortcuts in my Nautilus shortcut sidebar

Tags: gnome, nautilus, shortcuts

During the Covid lockdown, I did some long-term online substitute teaching for a local school district.  I, of course, had a district email and used the district's Google drive extensively.  So, I somehow managed to set up, in the Nautilus sidebar, a shortcut for each of my district email account and my district Google drive.  I'm not doing that now and need to delete those shortcuts.  However, when I right-click on the shortcut, the "remove" option is greyed out and inaccessible.  How do I get rid of these menu items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings >> online Accounts
you will see the google account/s you have connected under "connected to your data in the cloud"

Click on the account you want to remove shortcut of

a menu will pop up
here disable **Files option**

you can remove a remaining shortcut from calendar mails by disabling corresponding option or you can delete the account to completely remove it from the system